# Explicit change of basis for the Schur-Weyl basis 

Tags: rt.representation-theory, lie-algebras, canonical-bases

The Schur-Weyl duality states that $\bigotimes_{m=1}^n \mathbb{C}^k$ can be decomposed as a direct sum over the tensor product of irreductible representations of $SU(k)$ and of the symmetric group $\mathfrak{S}_n$.

If one considers the semi-normal representations of $SU(k)$ (resp. $\mathfrak{S}_n$), the irreducible representations of this groups are equipped with a basis indexed by semi-standard (resp. standard) Young tableaux whose shape $\lambda$ indexes the representation.

Putting everything together, we thus have a decomposition:
$$
\bigotimes_{m=1}^n \mathbb{C}^k  = \bigoplus_{(S,T) \text{ with shape $\lambda$ with $n$ boxes and at most $k$ lines}} (v_{S}\otimes v_T)
$$
and it should give a change of basis from the canonical basis of $\bigotimes_{m=1}^n \mathbb{C}^k$ to the basis $v_S\otimes v_T$ (on which $su(k)$ and $\mathfrak{S}_n$ acts in an easy way).

My question is (at least for small values of $k$ and $n$) : where can I find the matrix of the change of basis ? How can I compute it easily ?

Comment: In quantum computing this change of basis is known as _Schur transform_. In principle, it can be obtained as a sequence of so-called _Clebsch–Gordan transforms_ but it is quite tedious. Some relevant references: [Jakubczyk et al.](https://dx.doi.org/10.1140/epjd/e2014-50316-y), [Bacon et al.](https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0601001), and Chapter 5 of [Harrow's thesis](https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0512255).